# All Openoffice Document to Uppercase using basic

Tags: openoffice.org

Let be

> text msklakkdkdkdklalksksla

an openoffice document

How I can convert all strings of an openoffice document to Uppercase strings using openoffice basic (programing language similiar to visual basic)?

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice StarBasic has a (runtime) function `UCase`, which returns a given string in all upper case.

So, to change a (Writer!) document to upper case, someone can use a one-liner:

```
ThisComponent.Text.setString( UCase(ThisComponent.Text.String) )
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem with that instruction is the lost style (bold words, cursive words, etc).